# Magento 2.4 how to call out Bundle item selection attribute values?

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento2.4, bundled-product

Bundle item drop down selection name is called out like this:
`$this->escapeHtml($selection->getName())` in

> **Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle (Option.php)**

I want to call out the selection attribute.

`$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('pattern');` calls out bundle item attribute itself but
`$this->escapeHtml($selection->getAttributeText('pattern'))` does not work.

How to call out bundle item selection attributes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question myself. Attribute storefront "`Used in Product listing`" had to be set **Yes**

So `$this->escapeHtml($selection->getAttributeText('pattern'))` does work